# Sum of geometric series $\frac{7}{8} - \frac{49}{64} + \frac{343}{512}$

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{7}{8} - \frac{49}{64} + \frac{343}{512}...$$

I make the guess that this is suppose to be represented as

$$-1^{n+1} * (\frac{7}{8})^n$$

Now I use the formula my book gives

$$\Sigma_{n=M}^\inf -1^{n+1} = \frac{cr^M}{1 - r}$$

$$ \Sigma_{n=1}^\inf -1^{n+1} * (\frac{7}{8})^n$$

$$\frac{-1 \frac{7}{8}}{1 - \frac{7}{8}}$$

Why is this wrong? I copied the formula exactly and my representation of the series is correct.

Comment: It must be, in the final result, the first element of the series in the numerator, which is $\,\frac78\,$ in this case...

Comment: Your ratio is $-7/8$, not $7/8$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define

$$a=\frac78\;,\;\;q=-\frac78$$

Thus

$$|q|<1\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty aq^n=\frac a{1-q}=\frac{\frac78}{1+\frac78}=\frac7{15}$$

Comment: I don't follow where those terms came from, what happened to the -1?

Comment: Your geometric sequence is  $$ a=\frac78\;,\;aq=\frac78\left(-\frac78\right)=-\frac{49}{64}\;,$$ $$\;,aq^2=\frac78\left(\frac{7^2}{8^2}\right)=\frac{343}{512}\;\ldots$$ and thus its sum is what I wrote above...you know this formula, don't you?

Comment: I don't follow what you did, I thought my sequence was what I posted it was in the question.

Comment: Do you mean the series of $\,(-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac78\right)^n\;$ Well...yes, it's exactly the same if you begin with $\,n=1\;$ ! But its sum is not what you say it is...sorry.

Comment: So you started at 0?

Comment: Yes I did, it only a matter of convenience since passing to the limit we can see at once that $$|q|<1\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n=\frac1{1-q}$$$